# Validate Data formatting powershell

Tags: validation, date, powershell

i know it might be impossible to do what i need but i'm searching for a way to ensure that a user input date in the right format.
i have written a piece of code that can validate dates who the DD (day) part is between 13-31 but i'm struggling with the dates that has DD between 1-12

for ex:
i can validate  this date 23/06/2016 and fix it to be 06/23/2016 
but i can't ensure the date 12 of June is entered correctly.
if someone will input 12/06/2016 it's by definition a valid date but not the one i need (06/12/2016) and i can't really make sure that the date is the one i intended it to be

if any one can pleas point me to a solution it will be highly appreciated

if it makes any difference this is my code:

```
$Date = $args[0]
$Time = $args[1]

try
{
    $tmpDate = $Date +" " +$Time
    [DateTime]$UserDate = $tmpDate
}
catch
{
    $tmp = $Date
    $tmp -match "(?<d>.*)/(?<m>.*)/(?<y>.*)">$null
    $_Date = $matches['m']+"/"+$matches['d']+"/"+$matches['y']
    $tmpDate = $_Date +" " +$Time
    try
    {
        [DateTime]$UserDate = $tmpDate
    }

    catch
    {
        write-host "Error: The Given Date was not recognized as a valid Date, Please Try again" -ForegroundColor Red 
        Exit 808040
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way most programs work is that they ask the user to input date in the acceptable format. Displaying something like `YYYY/MM/DD` near the input box or prompt will help the user understand what program will accept. Then whatever user entered you can validate each part separately and warn the user if any part of the date is wrong.

Comment: the problem is not that i can't inform the user about the expected input, there is a big Tag that state what they need to input, but people sometimes don't really give a ***** about what they need to do  and how so i need to be prepared to any mistakes that might happen. anyway my struggle as i have already mentioned is that 12/06/2016 is a valid date and i have no way to check for formatting in this case.

Comment: Still relevant.